# Graphics not displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to develop a game in HTML5.  Right now the code is supposed to be displaying a canvas on the webpage and it's just not doing it. (I'm following a tutorial video).

**Here is the code for the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id="GameCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the code for game.js:**

```
// JavaScript Document

var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasHeight);

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');

canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "ship.png";

canvas.drawImage(image, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
```

Here is a screenshot of the directory I'm working in:

http://prntscr.com/4aucqt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<canvas id="GameCanvas"></canvas>`

vs

`$('#gameCanvas')`

Your IDs dont match.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Mikes Answer there are two other prolems:

First: Your HTML Document is not HTML5, look at your Doctype

Second: The image has to be fully loaded, unless you can draw it on the canvas. Simply use the onload callback:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
    canvas.drawImage(image, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
}
image.src = "ship.png";
```